# How to apply function to multiple samples in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to calculate fractional order derivative in MatLab using the following function

```
function Y = fgl_deriv( a, y, h )
%
%   Inputs:
%   a : fractional order
%   y : sampled function
%   h : period of the sampling lattice
%
%   Output:
%   Y : fractional derivative estimate given y

    n  = numel(y);
    J  = 0:(n-1);
    G1 = gamma( J+1 );
    G2 = gamma( a+1-J );
    s  = (-1) .^ J;

    M  = tril( ones(n) );
    R  = toeplitz( y(:)' );
    T  = meshgrid( (gamma(a+1)/(h^a)) * s ./ (G1.*G2) );
    Y  = reshape(sum( R .* M .* T, 2 ), size(y));
    
end
```

I could apply this function for one sample, like

```
values = [0.1579    0.1490  0.1424  0.1397  0.1367  0.1307  0.1264  0.1240  0.1223  0.1196  0.1167  0.1123  0.1077  0.1055  0.1032  0.1007  0.0984  0.0972  0.0966  0.0957  0.0938 ; 
    0.2043  0.1944  0.1878  0.1855  0.1829  0.1771  0.1735  0.1696  0.1661  0.1641  0.1615  0.1585  0.1548  0.1504  0.1478  0.1456  0.1427  0.1387  0.1382  0.1380  0.1348 ; 
    0.1807  0.1741  0.1667  0.1644  0.1611  0.1526  0.1488  0.1468  0.1445  0.1409  0.1384  0.1350  0.1309  0.1278  0.1258  0.1235  0.1208  0.1184  0.1167  0.1160  0.1154];
headers = {'W1', 'W2', 'W3', 'W4', 'W5', 'W6', 'W7', 'W8', 'W9', 'W10', 'W11', 'W12', 'W13', 'W14', 'W15', 'W16', 'W17', 'W18', 'W19', 'W20', 'W21'};

x = values(1,:);
h = 1; 

% Compute fractional derivatives with different orders
order = 0:0.1:1;
yd    = zeros( length(order), length(x) );

for i=1:length(order)
    yd(i,:) = fgl_deriv( order(i), x, h );
end
```

The output for one sample is like the following

```
Order   W1  W2  W3  W4  W5  W6  W7  W8  W9  W10 W11 W12 W13 W14 W15 W16 W17 W18 W19 W20 W21
0   0.158   0.149   0.142   0.140   0.137   0.131   0.126   0.124   0.122   0.120   0.117   0.112   0.108   0.106   0.103   0.101   0.098   0.097   0.097   0.096   0.094
0.1 0.158   0.133   0.120   0.114   0.109   0.101   0.096   0.093   0.090   0.087   0.084   0.079   0.075   0.073   0.070   0.068   0.066   0.065   0.064   0.064   0.062
0.2 0.158   0.117   0.100   0.092   0.085   0.076   0.071   0.068   0.065   0.062   0.059   0.054   0.050   0.048   0.047   0.045   0.043   0.042   0.042   0.041   0.039
0.3 0.158   0.102   0.081   0.072   0.065   0.056   0.051   0.048   0.046   0.043   0.040   0.036   0.032   0.031   0.029   0.028   0.026   0.026   0.026   0.026   0.024
0.4 0.158   0.086   0.064   0.055   0.048   0.039   0.035   0.033   0.031   0.028   0.026   0.022   0.019   0.019   0.018   0.016   0.015   0.015   0.015   0.015   0.014
0.5 0.158   0.070   0.048   0.040   0.034   0.026   0.022   0.021   0.020   0.017   0.015   0.012   0.010   0.010   0.009   0.008   0.008   0.008   0.009   0.008   0.007
0.6 0.158   0.054   0.034   0.028   0.022   0.015   0.013   0.012   0.012   0.010   0.008   0.005   0.004   0.004   0.004   0.003   0.003   0.004   0.004   0.004   0.003
0.7 0.158   0.038   0.022   0.017   0.013   0.007   0.006   0.006   0.006   0.004   0.003   0.001   0.000   0.001   0.001   0.000   0.000   0.001   0.002   0.001   0.000
0.8 0.158   0.023   0.011   0.009   0.006   0.001   0.001   0.002   0.002   0.001   0.000   -0.002  -0.003  -0.001  -0.001  -0.001  -0.001  0.000   0.000   0.000   -0.001
0.9 0.158   0.007   0.001   0.002   0.001   -0.003  -0.002  -0.001  0.000   -0.001  -0.002  -0.004  -0.004  -0.002  -0.002  -0.002  -0.002  -0.001  0.000   -0.001  -0.002
1   0.158   -0.009  -0.007  -0.003  -0.003  -0.006  -0.004  -0.002  -0.002  -0.003  -0.003  -0.004  -0.005  -0.002  -0.002  -0.003  -0.002  -0.001  -0.001  -0.001  -0.002
```

Now how can I apply it for all the samples with index columns for identification like

```
Sample  Order
    1   0
    1   0.1
    1   0.2
    1   0.3
    1   0.4
    1   0.5
    1   0.6
    1   0.7
    1   0.8
    1   0.9
    1   1
    2   0
    2   0.1
    2   0.2
    2   0.3
    2   0.4
    2   0.5
    2   0.6
    2   0.7
    2   0.8
    2   0.9
    2   1
    3   0
    3   0.1
    3   0.2
    3   0.3
    3   0.4
    3   0.5
    3   0.6
    3   0.7
    3   0.8
    3   0.9
    3   1
```

I am open to software like R or Python for this problem.

Comment: Hello, just got a link to this, I only know python and R/Rcpp. have no clue with matlab. Sorry dont know what fractional order derivatives are. Instead of just tagging matlab, consider structuring the question such that you have the problem in psedo format. Then tag one language. ie ask the question in R and ask the same question in python. in that way you will have high chance for someone to help. Most people use python/R. unless you are a mathematician then you use matlab/mathematica.

Comment: @Onyambu There is one package in Python [pyfod](https://github.com/prmiles/pyfod). I want to implement Grünwald-Letnikov method for this data. Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: To be fair that will be a lot of work. Understanding the ins and outs of a package require a quite amout of time using it. -- parharps just understanding the matlab code on what is happening is all that is needed. and then one can implement the code in any language without the need of a package. In your function above, i can see `J = 0:(N-1)` ie asequence from 0 to n-1, gamma(j) and (-1)^.j --vectorized version in matlab i assume. I just dont know what `numel` is. I assume `toeplitz` is the circular matrix.

Comment: I also dont know whether .* is an elementwise multiplication.. etc I believe if you could explain each of the lines in a pseudo format then this can easily be implemented in any language.

Comment: `numel` returns the number of elements in an array. `toeplitz` is the function in R  for same operation.

Comment: cout you include an example of output from the input vector

Comment: @Onyambu I have included the output for one sample in the question.